# Where is Preferences DataStore (Jetpack) stored?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-jetpack-datastore

SharedPreferences (though has many downsides) has the upside of accessing the XML where the data is stored.

Where does Jetpack DataStore store the data and is the file accessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the file stored by DataStore is accessible.

It is located in data/data/yourApplicationPackageName/files/datastore/nameOfYourFile.preferences_db

Option 1:
To go inside that folder, make sure you have the permission.
Run the following commands
adb root,
adb remount,
adb shell,
cd data/data/yourApplicationPackageName/files/datastore/

Option 2:
Once the device is connected in Android Studio, select Device File Explorer. Expand the folders data/data/yourApplicationPackageName/files/datastore/

Open the file and it should contain the preferences data.